# Inner Join Query with 2 tables giving different result compared to Sub Query for same 2 tables Northwind database

Tags: sql-server, subquery, northwind

Using Northwind Database = 2 tables = Orders and Customers.  Need to get Companies that Placed Order in 1997 (OrderDate).

Orders table Data:

```
OrderID CustomerID  EmployeeID  OrderDate   RequiredDate    ShippedDate ShipVia Freight ShipName    ShipAddress ShipCity    ShipRegion  ShipPostalCode  ShipCountry
```

Customers Table Data:

```
CustomerID  CompanyName ContactName ContactTitle    Address City    Region  PostalCode  Country Phone   Fax
```

I have run 2 queries one is with Inner join and Other is a Sub Query.  The inner join Query gives output of 408 rows while the  SubQuery gives output of 86 rows.  I feel the subquery Groups the CustomerID together. Not sure which query is correct for the question to get Companies that placed order in 1997

INNER JOIN Query

```
Select a.OrderID, a.CustomerID, b.CompanyName,a.OrderDate
from Orders a
inner join Customers b on a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
where a.OrderDate between '1997-01-01' AND '1997-12-31'
```

SUB Query

```
SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName
FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN (SELECT CustomerID
            FROM Orders
            WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '1997-01-01' AND '1997-12-31');
```

I am brushing up on my SQL skills and was using Northwind Database for practice, so would like to know which query is correct to answer the question

Comment: What is the data type of `OrderDate`? If it's not a `date`, then the results will likely not be quite right for either query. Based on the question, the latter is likely what they are after (depending on data type), but you should really be using aliases in both questions (and not `a`, `b`, `c`, etc... [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3))

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is what you're returning. In the subquery example, you are returning just the rows from the Customers table who have orders in the subquery - so a row per customer.
In the inner join example, you are returning data from both the Customers and the Orders table - so a row per customer and per order.

If a customer has 5 orders, the subquery example will return a single row - for the customer. In the inner join example, the query will return 5 rows - one for every order the customer has made.

This might help explain the inner join logic further: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/inner-join-operation-microsoft-access-sql